# Change states from a group of components and render new table component after onClick event react js

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-router, use-state

I want to render a new table after onClick() event on a group of buttons. The table is supposed to be larger or smaller depending on the clicked button which represent the difficulty level of a game. I used two states: "selected" and "difficulty". The first one let the application redirect to "/game" route if a button has been clicked; the second one just keep track of the selected button and tells how much larger the table would be. I don't know how to modify difficulty with the proper value (1 for "easy", 3 for "difficult") in setDifficulty(selected_button) after calling handleSubmit in onCllick() function.
This is my DifficultButtons.js:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSelected(true); //here i want to use setDifficulty(selected_button)
}
return (
    <>
        {selected ? <Link to={{
            pathname: '/game',
            state: {level : difficulty}
        }} /> :
            <ButtonGroup size="lg" className="d-grid gap-3 below-nav">
                <Row className='main-font'>choose difficulty:</Row>

                <Button variant="warning" size="lg" active level={1} onClick={handleSubmit>very Easy</Button>{' '}

                <Button variant="warning" size="lg" active level={2} onClick={handleSubmit}>easy</Button>{' '}

                <Button variant="warning" size="lg" active level={3} onClick={handleSubmit)}>Medium</Button>{' '}
            </ButtonGroup>
        }
```

Then in GameTable.js i would use setLocation() to take the state an render a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the implementation of `ButtonGroup` and `Button` an easy way would be to curry the difficulty level in the click handler.

Update `handleClick` to curry a `difficulty` argument and return am `onClick` handler function. This closes over in callback scope a difficulty value for passing to the state updater function.

```
const handleClick = (difficulty) => (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setSelected(true);
  setDifficulty(difficulty);
};
```

Invoke `handleClick` and pass the appropriate difficulty level. This closes over the passed difficulty value and returns the `onClick` callback to attach button's `onClick` handler.

```
return (
  <>
    {selected ? (
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: '/game',
          state: { level : difficulty }
        }}
      />
    ) : (
      <ButtonGroup size="lg" className="d-grid gap-3 below-nav">
        <Row className='main-font'>choose difficulty:</Row>

        <Button
          variant="warning"
          size="lg"
          active
          level={1}
          onClick={handleSubmit(1)}
        >
          very Easy
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="warning"
          size="lg"
          active
          level={2}
          onClick={handleSubmit(2)}
        >
          easy
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="warning"
          size="lg"
          active
          level={3}
          onClick={handleSubmit(3)}
        >
          Medium
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    )}
  </>
);
```